# Result of call to my method is unused during initialization

Tags: swift, class, struct, initialization

I am trying to get my `greet()` method in my `Dog` class to initialize during the creation of a dog object in testing. I keep getting the message `"Result of call to 'greet()' is unused"`. Can anyone help me, please?

```
class Dog {

private var name: String

init(name:String) {
    self.name = name
    self.greet()
    }

func greet() -> String{
    let greeeting = "the user's name is \(name)."
    print(greeeting)
    return greeting 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are not using the variable which you return the string in function
If you do not want to use the return type remove the Return type. or call directly from the function

Comment: Can you try to explain in detail? @AdarshKC

Answer (score 2):

The function `greet()` is defined with a `String` return type. But since you don't use the returned value in any way, the compiler tries to warn you that you might have forgotten something.

Try adding `@discardableResult` :

```
@discardableResult func greet() -> String{
        
        let greeeting = "the user's name is \(name)."
        print(greeeting)
        return greeting 
        
     }
}
```